# NameError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::ADMIN_USERNAME):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a simple website with password protected admin area. It works fine in development. When I upload to Heroku I get the following error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::ADMIN_USERNAME):
```

My application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protected
  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == ENV[ADMIN_USERNAME] && password == ENV[ADMIN_PASSWORD]
    end
  end
end
```

Admin/index_controller:

```
class Admin::IndexController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate
  def index
  end
end
```

I have set heroku env varibale with:

```
heroku config:add ADMIN_USERNAME:'myusername'
```

I'm not able to find what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ENV['ADMIN_USERNAME']`, otherwise the app thinks it's a constant name. Altough it's weird that this works in development.

Comment: ok, now I get to login form, but it doesn't do anything. heroku logs give me: Filter chain halted as :authenticate rendered or redirected

Comment: did you set 'ADMIN_PASSWORD' env variable on Heroku?

Comment: Yes, I did. I find it funny too, that all of the tutorials I've found just hardcode usr and pwd right in the controller.

Comment: Then I guess, you'll need to debug, what is the output of `username == ENV['ADMIN_USERNAME'] && password == ENV['ADMIN_PASSWORD']` on the server... and maybe debug, if the `ENV['ADMIN_USERNAME']` and `ENV['ADMIN_PASSWORD']` are set correctly.